# Vue Router should not redirect if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I use Firebase auth with Vuejs and Vue Router.
I have the pages Home, Login, SignUp and Tasks.
I want that when the user is logged in and goes to the Login or SignUp page he will get redirected to the Tasks page but if he goes to the Home page he should not get redirected to the Tasks page. I don't know how to configure this and ask for help.

I have the following code:

```
    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
      },
      {
        path: '/signup',
        name: 'SignUp',
        component: SignUp
      },
      {
        path: '/tasks',
        name: 'Tasks',
        component: Tasks,
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      { path: "*", redirect: {path: '/'} }
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: "history",
      routes
    });


    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
      if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('login');
      else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser){next('tasks')}
      else next();
    });

    let app;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function () {
      if(!app){
        new Vue({
          router,
          render (h) {
            return h(App)
          }
        }).$mount('#app');
      }
    });
```

**Solution**

I have added a meta tag to the Home path and added an if clause in the router function.

Solution code :

```
    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
        // I added this meta tag to the Home path.
        meta: {
          loggedin: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
      },
      {
        path: '/signup',
        name: 'SignUp',
        component: SignUp
      },
      {
        path: '/tasks',
        name: 'Tasks',
        component: Tasks,
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
      { path: "*", redirect: {path: '/'} }
    ]
    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: "history",
      routes
    });

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
      const loggedin = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.loggedin);
      // I added the if clause under this text.
      if (loggedin && currentUser) next();
      else if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('login');
      else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('tasks');
      else next();
    });

    let app;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function () {
      if(!app){
        new Vue({
          router,
          render (h) {
            return h(App)
          }
        }).$mount('#app');
      }
    });
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: The problem is that when the user is logged in he gets redirected if he visits the Home page. I want that if the user is logged in and visits the Home page that he won't get redirected to the Tasks page.